# Custom URL scheme not recognized as link in SMS app(only in iphone 4 iOS 5.0)

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, sms

Summary:
In my application, I've defined a custom URL in the format "myapp://.." . But the URL is not recognized as a link when it comes in an SMS. So the user is not able to tap it and launch the app. Instead, he has to copy & paste it in browser. This happens only in iPhone4(iOS v5.0)

Steps to Reproduce:
Define a custom URL for the app by specifying a new URL scheme in info.plist. Send an SMS with the custom URL of the app to iPhone4(iOS v5.0). Open the SMS.

Expected Result:
The URL must be displayed as link in the SMS.

Actual Result:
The URL is displayed there as plain text and not as a link.

Regression:
Before upgrading to iOS 5, in the same iPhone4(iOS version 4.3), the URL was displayed as link always.

Notes:
The funny side is that, if I forward the message from the same iPhone to itself, in the sent SMS and the newly received SMS, the URL will appear as a link.

Comment: Have you considered reporting this bug to Apple? Unless there is a work around I don't think anyone can help you here.

Comment: have the same issue, does anybody has a solution?

Comment: Is the behavior limited to incoming SMS messages? For instance, if the same link is received in an incoming email in iOS 5, does it correctly work as a link?

Comment: tHis is limited to incoming SMS messages. The link when received in an incoming email in iOS5 works correctly.

Comment: After further, review, it appears that the FaceBook custom url (e.g. fb://profile) works in SMS -- always.)  Anyone have further insight into why the FaceBook custom URL works but ours do not?

Comment: Are you sending a parameter in the url? I just tried it, and sending myapp:// wasn't recognized in the SMS, but sending myapp://aaa was recognized correctly.

Comment: This is a bug in iOS 5. The url parser sometimes works, and sometimes it doesn't. File a bug report with Apple, and they'll eventually fix it. After extensive testing, I found that this bug even occurs with http:// links sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you're using uppercase/mixed scheme (as in MyApp://...) versus an all lowercase (myapp://...). Under iOS 5, the OS won't recognize and will throw exceptions if you try to use uppercase in a custom URL scheme. If that doesn't work, it's almost certainly a bug with the SMS code in which case you should file a bug. Let me know if that worked.

Comment: Can you accept one of these answers or say if it didn't work?

Comment: I had tried it but that too didn't worked. Anyway as you said I am filing this as a bug to Apple.

Comment: did not work for me either, tested on iPhone 7 Beta 4. Never tested on older versions of iOS though :(

Answer (score 2):

It seems the SMS url parser is not clever enough to work out that your url is for an app - my suggestion would be to use an http:// based url that will then redirect to the url for your app.

This would allow you to show a message to non iPhone users who might have inadvertently got the message and would also allow you to register that the SMS linked has clicked on all this is in addition to also working on iOS 5.

Answer (score 1):

in iOS 5.0.1 it works but you should append some arbitrary text BEFORE the link.

Comment: This URL: 'custom://magsw.com?x=movie.mp4' needed space before it in order to show as hyperlink.  'custom://movie.mp4' did not.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting your phone shell resolve this problem.